# What's the probability distribution of an edge length of a polygon, whose other edges are less than l?

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-distributions, plane-geometry, geometric-probability

A polygon (not necessarily convex), with $m$ edges. $m-1$ of these edges are less than $l$.

What's the probability distribution of the other edge length?
When $$m=3$$
<s>I'm not sure. But it seems the answer is</s>
$$F(x) = P(M_3 < x) = \frac{\arccos(\frac{m_1^2+m_2^2-x^2}{2m_1m_2})}{\pi}$$

<s>If it's correct. How about $m>3$?</s>

So it's wrong.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

$(m+1)$ Points are randomly placed on an infinite plane. But we have priori knowledge, that there has been $m$ edges ( a chain ) shorter than  $l$

Comment: I see no reason I cannot make it have uniform distribution on the interval $(0,(m-1)l)$. You have to say what random processes underlie the choosing of the polygon if you want something more specific. As a side note, I would assume from the problem wording that we only had $l$ to work with, and not the specific $m_i$.

Comment: @Arthur. Thanks. You're right, it has nothing to do with specific $m_i$.

Comment: @Arthur. If it follows $U(0, (m-1)l)$, how do you prove it ? Thanks again.

Comment: It follows because you haven't specified _how_ we choose the random polygon. If I'm careful, I can make the selection process in such a way that the length of the last side happens to become uniformly random.

Comment: $(m+1)$ Points are randomly placed on an infinite plane. But we have priori knowledge, that there has been $m$ edges ( a chain ) shorter than $l$.

Comment: What does it mean for $m+1$ points to be randomly placed on an infinite plane? Are the points placed independently? What is the underlying distribution? Note that there is no uniform distribution on the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer just too long for comments:

In your example, it seems the one vertex is placed on $(0, 0)$, another on $(M_1, 0)$ and the third one is $(M_2\cos\Theta, M_2\sin\Theta)$, where $M_1, M_2 \sim \text{Uniform}(0, l)$, $\Theta \sim \text{Uniform}(0, \pi)$ and they are independent. By Law of Cosine,

$$ M_3^2 = M_1^2 + M_2^2 - 2M_1M_2\cos\Theta$$

Therefore 
$$\begin{align} \Pr\{M_3 \leq x|M_1 = m_1, M_2 = m_2\} 
&= \Pr\{M_3^2 \leq x^2|M_1 = m_1, M_2 = m_2\} \\
&= \Pr\{m_1^2 + m_2^2 - 2m_1m_2\cos\Theta\leq x^2\} \\
&= \Pr\left\{\cos\Theta \geq \frac {m_1^2 + m_2^2 - x^2} {2m_1m_2}\right\} \\
&= \Pr\left\{\Theta \leq \arccos\left(\frac {m_1^2 + m_2^2 - x^2} {2m_1m_2}\right)\right\} \\
&= \frac {1} {\pi}\arccos\left(\frac {m_1^2 + m_2^2 - x^2} {2m_1m_2}\right)
\end{align}$$

As said if you want to generalize the problem you need to specify more.

Comment: Thanks. And I found a research into this: On Multihop Distances in Wireless Sensor Networks with Random Node Locations. Serdar Vural,  Eylem Ekici.